# CAShapeLayer performance

Tags: performance, macos, cocoa, core-animation, cashapelayer

It is my understanding that `CAShapeLayer` basically draws it's shape into a `CGImageRef`. So if I was to instead draw the shape myself into a `CGImageRef` context and set that as the content of a plain `CALayer`, I would get similar performance and memory usage.

Is this a correct assumption, or is `CAShapeLayer` doing something magical under the hood?

Comment: You would most likely not get the same performance (at least not for animations) but as always you should measure yourself.